# Java : read file and stop at new line context

Tags: java

For example, given a txt file:

```
words
123
words:123
words:324

words
123
words:123
words:324
```

Is it possible to do this?

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(//the txt file mentioned above); 
Scanner s = new Scanner(fr).useDelimiter(//something which equal to the empty string after each venue);
while (s.hasNext()){
        String paragraph = s.next();
        break;
    }
```

Is it possible to read just up to a blank line? So paragraph would be equal to :

```
words
123
words:123
words:324
```

Comment: Just use `String` concatenation, and put a newline (`\n`) character after each line that you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to break your input file into pieces delimited by a blank line, something like this might work:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(//the txt file mentioned above); 
Scanner s = new Scanner(fr);
while (s.hasNext()){
    String paragraph = new String();
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        String line = s.next();
        if (line.length() == 0)
            break;
        if (paragraph.length() != 0)
            paragraph = paragraph + "\n";
        paragraph = paragraph + "\n" + line;
    }
    // Do something with paragraph here...           
}
```

Comment: This is the key: `if (line.length() == 0) break;`

Answer (score 0):

**See if this helps**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

File your_file = new File("D:/text_document.txt"); //your text file
Scanner sc = new Scanner(your_file); // initialize your 
//scanner with text file
String s ="";
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    s =s+sc.nextLine()+"\n";    
}
System.out.println(s);
sc.close();
}
```